# how can we have implicit in json

Tags: java, json, xstream

Do we have any annotation that can replace @xstreamImplicit for JSON as XstreamImplicit works only for XML?

Eg:

```
Class A {

  @XstreamImplicit
  private List<Apple> apples;
}
```

XML:

```
<apple>
  .....
  .....
</apple>
<apple>
   ....
   ....
</apple>
```

JSON  :

```
{ apples: [{...}] }
```

I want the desired output of JSON in the following format :

```
[{...}]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to ["Write to JSON with the self-contained JSON driver dropping the root" in the JSON tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html#json-dropping-root), you can write something like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver() {
    public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer writer) {
        return new JsonWriter(writer, JsonWriter.DROP_ROOT_MODE);
    }
});
```

Comment: @ruack hey thanks buddy.
But the object of Class A what i Have mentioned is not the root element.
It is has a reference inside class C which supposed to be the root class.

    class B {
          @XstreamAlias("fruit")
          private A a:
    }

Comment: And do we have any annotations similar to xstreamImplicit which will do the needfull of dropping the tag or key : for json

Comment: @user1065080: For that, I guess you need to use `JettisonMappedXmlDriver` (which serializes to XML and then translates to JSON; see [its Javadoc](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/json/JettisonMappedXmlDriver.html)) instead of `JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing some thing like this,

I do not approve that this method works fine while re creating the object from the string obtained from this.

```
Class A {

  private List<Apple> apples;
  public static void setXstreamAlias(XStream xstream)
      xstream.alias("apples", List.class, Apple.class);
      xstream.addImplicitArray(A.class, "apples");
  }
}
```

This method should be called before you do that object to string serialization.

like this,

```
A a = new A();
// setting some values to your apple here...
.
.
.

// finally
XStream xstream;
xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
A.setXstreamAlias(xstream);
String output = xstream.toXML(a) ;
```

I hope this helped you,

But this is having some issue, 
go through this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966871/xstream-json-arraylist-handling-after-xstreamimplicit-the-arraylist-variable

Adnd correct If I am wrong any of the above understandings. Thank you.